# Consulta sobre middlewares nodejs

Tags: nodejs, express-session

tengo la siguiente rutas y los siguiente middlewares

```
router.use(logged.unlogged);
router.use("/logout",logged.logged);
router.route("/login").get(login.login_get).post(login.login_post);
router.route("/recuperar").get(recuperar.recuperar_get).post(recuperar.recuperar_post);
router.route("/registrar").get(registrar.registrar_get).post(registrar.registrar_post);
router.route("/logout").get(logout);
module.exports=router;
```

Middlewares

```
var logged=function(req,res,next){

    if(req.session.user_id!=undefined){
        console.log("logged if");
        next();
    }
    else{
        console.log("logged error");
        return res.redirect("/");
    }
}

    var unlogged=function(req,res,next){
        if(req.session.user_id!=undefined){
            console.log("El usuario ya esta logeado",Date.now());
            return res.redirect("/");

        }
        else{
            console.log("unlogged else",req.session.user_id); 
            next();
        }
    }


    module.exports={
        logged:logged,
        unlogged:unlogged
    }
```

Lo que pasa es lo siguiente , cuando ejecuto , y por ejemplo ingreso a user/login , me logeo se guarda una sesion en memoria y almaceno el id en 
req.session.user_id,luego de esto puse esos middlewares para que si quisiera entrar a alguno de esos endpoints logeado simplemente me redirigiera ,pero en el caso de logout , lo que queria era que si estaba logeado simplemente cerrada la sesion poniendole req.session.user_id=undefined(¿Esto esta bien?).

Sucede que me logeo se activa la sesion , si intento ingresar a login , recuperar,registrar me redirige , pero cuando intento ingresar a logout tambien me redirige sin cerra la sesion , se ejecuta el primer middleware, pero yo le puse para que se ejecute el 2° , como veo lo lee secuencial y deberia haber un next para que lea el segundo , lo podria poner usando algo como req.path.indexOf("logout") , pero mi pregunta es si hay otra forma de darle mas importancia por asi decir al 2° middleware desde mi ruta usando use.

Edito lo he hecho de esta manera que me parece mas lógica.

```
var unlogged=function(req,res,next){
    if(req.session.user_id!=undefined){
        if(req.path.indexOf("logout")>0)next();
        console.log("El usuario ya esta logeado",Date.now());
        return res.redirect("/");

    }
    else{
        console.log("unlogged else",req.session.user_id); 
        next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No veo necesario un middleware para cerrar la sesión del usuario. Simplemente comprobaría allí mismo si está logueado. Si lo está destruyo la sesión, luego redirigo al index (y si no está logueado también).

```
app.get('/logout', (request, response) => {
  if(request.session.id) {
    request.session.destroy();
  }
  response.render('index');
});
```

Comment: si eso podría hacerlo , pero el tema esque igual antes pasaria por el primer middleware ya que estos usando router para encapsular todo bajo /user, si quisiera hacer eso deberia poner en el primer middleware algo como if(req.path.indexOf("logout")>0)next();
solo busco varias formas de  hacerlo.

Comment: No tienes necesidad de poner un middleware al logout. La petición debe ser directa, sin nada más. Los middleware están bien para las áreas protegidas.

Comment: si creo que tienes razón lo cambie un poco ,puedes darle una mirada

Comment: Sí, me parece correcto.